# Should we reject edits that remove the automatic duplicate notification?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just rejected [this edit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/129349/3) that was suggested on this question: [How can I tell bad code from good code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129349/how-can-i-tell-bad-code-from-good-code)

The edit did correct a spelling mistake in the title (as the edit comment suggested), but also removed the duplicate notification that was applied automatically when the question was closed. My reasoning was that there wasn't any significant improvement on the edit that made the question not a dupe, and even if there was, there's no reason to remove the notification until (and if) the question is reopened.

Questions:

1. Was rejecting the edit justified?
2. What if there were far more significant edits?
3. Are there any repercussions for the user who suggested the edit? I'm only asking because of the scary reject dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Manual edits should ***never*** remove the auto inserted duplicate text.

The only mitigating factor might be that he started his edit before the question was closed as a duplicate. The edit time and close time are approximately the same so that's entirely possible.

The only ramifications for the user would be if he had multiple consecutive edits rejected. Then he would be barred from suggesting edits for a week.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something... Will check the timestamps next time :) Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in this case, I noted that he or she suggested the change as I was closing the question, so I opted to improve the suggestion by re-adding the notification manually.